# How to use python output generated by several print statements?

Tags: python

I have a function which generates a large amount of output, like such

```
A: {B:1,C:0,D:3}
B: {A:1,C:0,D:3}
C: {B:1,A:0,D:3}
D: {B:1,C:0,A:3}

min = 0, x = A, y = C, new = AC

AC: {B:1,D:3}
B: {AC:1,D:3}
D: {B:1,AC:0}

min = 0, x = B, y = AC, new = ACB
```

Essentially, Im using a function (for arguments sake we'll call it 'fun1') which generates the type of output like shown above.

Im looking at doing something like data1 = fun1(input), and then using this variable as input to another function, along with some other input too.

So how do I utilize this information? I'm used to dealing with lists, dictionaries and what not, as output from a function. Im trying to access the information so that I can find out certain things about the relationship of a certain letter to others. Also it the amount of output above is just 2 lists of letters, but thats totally arbitrary.

Help please :)

Comment: is fun1 returning the data with a statement like `return {A:{...}, B:{...}}` or is it printing the information with statements like `print "%s" % ADictionary` ?

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you're asking. Do you want to return multiple variables from a function? Do you want to return a string of your output?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer, Im new to python. fun1 is a function which includes multiple print statements inside a while loop. But what Im asking is how to do I use the information inside the variable data1.

Comment: Thats all being printed from a function? If you are running this function in another process, then you would have to read stdout and parse this data. Is there any reason why you have to print this data and not just return an actual object?

Comment: Maybe the function just prints some stuff and returns `None`. You could try showing us the function or at least the output of `print data1`

Comment: Okay sorry again for the confusion, like I said Im new to all this, and this function was written by another researcher who's given me the code for this project Im working on. Basically the function fun1 prints out dictionaries at various points when its running. But it doesn't just return the dictionary in the normal way that python would, it calls another function to print out the dictionary in the nice formatted way that you see above. Does that help?

Comment: Also I don't have the actual programs with me at the moment, just print offs of them, which are quite long, the files are stored on my office computer, Im working from home right now and was hoping to get some understanding of how to utilize this function before beginning work on it tomorrow.

Comment: Unfortunately, that "nice formatted" way isn't very helpful to you. Other than visually seeing the data and going "hmm thats pretty good data", you now have to do a whole bunch of work to parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not clear to me why you have a function that prints out tons of data as opposed to returning it as a useable python object. If you have control of this function (its yours and you wrote it), then it should be doing something like this (keep in mind that this is regardless of efficiency or whatever. Just trying to make it simple for you)...

```
def fun1():

    allresults = []

    # do you loop and generate objects like
    results = {
        "A": {"B":1,"C":0,"D":3},
        "B": {"A":1,"C":0,"D":3},
        "C": {"B":1,"A":0,"D":3},
        "D": {"B":1,"C":0,"A":3},
        "min": 0,
        "x": "A",
        "y": "C",
        "new": "AC" 
    }

    # and add them to your list
    allresults.append(results)

    return allresults
```

Then when you ran your function, you would have a return value:

```
data = fun1()
```

If you do not have control over the source of this function (its part of some other strangely written library), then the only clean way would be to run it in another process and read the stdout out. Then parse that into something useable. Otherwise you are talking about redirecting the stdout pipe temporarily while running this function, but I am not even gunna go there.

#### Update

In your comments you said that this is part of some other library. Your best bet is to make changes to this code and get it to properly return its data so that its reusable. Your biggest issue here is that what is being printed isnt even in a common format. At the very least it could have dumped out JSON or something like that to be parsed by another process.

Comment: I've edited your answer to clarify your usage of `results` (list/dict)

Comment: @Alex: Ah whoops! That was a typo. I had meant to call the single element `result` and the list `results`. Thank you!